# Server Response Header "Cowboy"

Tags: node.js, express

In the `Server` response header returned from my site hosted on Heroku and served by `NodeJS`/`express`, I see the value `Cowboy`.

- Who's outputting that value for `Server`?
- Bonus, what's the "etymology"/reason for using `Cowboy` as the value for `Server`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That would probably be [heroku/cowboy](https://github.com/heroku/cowboy). "Cowboy" is just an arbitrary project name that [ninenines/cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy) chose. It's just as random as "Apache" (a patchy version of its predecessor), "nginx", "unicorn", etc.

Answer (score 4):

Bonus answer "etymology": It doesn't say on it's GitHub page (https://github.com/heroku/cowboy), but here are some guesses:

- Because it runs on Ranch (https://github.com/heroku/ranch): Ranch is a socket acceptor pool for TCP protocols?
- Possibly also because it sees Apache as a competitor?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your questions:

Who's outputting that value for Server? It's a HTTP server called Cowboy. Cowboy is a small, fast and modular HTTP server written in Erlang.

Bonus, what's the "etymology"/reason for using Cowboy as the value for Server?
It's a way to identify that your requests are being processed by Cowboy. You could check the following links, with the Cowboy docs.

[Cowboy](https://github.com/ninenines/cowboy)
[Cowboy handler docs](http://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/HEAD/guide/handlers/)